# Get Aurora Data API to return JSON

Tags: python

I'm using the aurora-data-api to get results from AWS Aurora serverless (postgres) in my Lambda. I'm using the following code to format the results.

```
with aurora_data_api.connect(aurora_cluster_arn=cluster_arn, secret_arn=secret_arn, database="redwave_db_staging") as conn:
        with conn.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute("SELECT d.uuid, d.name, dl.id, dl.temp FROM devices d LEFT JOIN device_log dl ON dl.device_uuid=d.uuid")
            fields = [i[0] for i in cursor.description]
            result = [dict(zip(fields,row)) for row in cursor.fetchall()]
```

This works fine for a simple (non-join) queries but when I do a join I don't get any nested data. Instead, I get results like this....

```
[
 {'id': 1, 'name': 'device 1', 'temp': '5.0', 'uuid': 'aaaa-bbbb-cccc'},
 {'id': 2, 'name': 'device 1', 'temp': '5.1', 'uuid': 'aaaa-bbbb-cccc'},
 {'id': 3, 'name': 'device 2', 'temp': '6.2', 'uuid': 'bbbb-cccc-dddd'}
]
```

I'd rather have results like this...

```
[
 {
   'uuid': 'aaaa-bbbb-cccc' 
   'name': 'device 1', 
   'info': [
     {'id': 1, 'temp': '5.0'},
     {'id': 2, 'temp': '5.1'}
    ],
 },
 {
   'uuid': 'bbbb-cccc-dddd' 
   'name': 'device 2', 
   'info': [
     {'id': 3, 'temp': '6.0'}
    ],
 }
]
```

Can anyone offer any assistance in getting my JSON data to be nested?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly whay you have asked for - but a data structure that makes more sense.

```
import pprint

d1 = [
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'device 1', 'temp': '5.0', 'uuid': 'aaaa-bbbb-cccc'},
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'device 1', 'temp': '5.1', 'uuid': 'aaaa-bbbb-cccc'},
    {'id': 3, 'name': 'device 2', 'temp': '6.2', 'uuid': 'bbbb-cccc-dddd'}
]
d2 = {}
for e in d1:
    if e['uuid'] not in d2:
        d2[e['uuid']] = {'name': e['name'], 'info': [{'id': e['id'], 'temp': e['temp']}]}
    else:
        d2[e['uuid']]['info'].append({'id': e['id'], 'temp': e['temp']})
pprint.pprint(d2)
```

output

```
{'aaaa-bbbb-cccc': {'info': [{'id': 1, 'temp': '5.0'},
                             {'id': 2, 'temp': '5.1'}],
                    'name': 'device 1'},
 'bbbb-cccc-dddd': {'info': [{'id': 3, 'temp': '6.2'}], 'name': 'device 2'}}
```

if you want to have the list

```
lst = []
for k, v in d2.items():
    lst.append({'uuid': k})
    lst[-1].update(v)
pprint.pprint(lst)
```

output

```
[{'info': [{'id': 1, 'temp': '5.0'}, {'id': 2, 'temp': '5.1'}],
  'name': 'device 1',
  'uuid': 'aaaa-bbbb-cccc'},
 {'info': [{'id': 3, 'temp': '6.2'}],
  'name': 'device 2',
  'uuid': 'bbbb-cccc-dddd'}]
```

Comment: This is great!  Thanks so much.